# Remove "The field must be a number" default validation text on decimal property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have .cshtml file with code below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Level)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Level)
```

And property in model:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage="Only two places after comma")]
public decimal? Level {get; set;}
```

If I put the comma in the form it shows me info "The field Level must be a number". When I write the number after a comma then these communicate disappoint. How can I remove this default validation message?

Comment: Isn't it expected behaviour, I mean `2,` is invalid but `2,1` is valid. Why do you want to remove `must be a number` validation?

Comment: @ocanal I want to show only messsge from regex. Not other. If I write "2," and then display communicate from regex it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually expected behaviour but if you still don't want that default number validation message, there are two options.

You can just remove `number` validation on client side,

```
$("#Level").rules("remove", 'number');
```

Or you can change property type to `String` on server side.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage="Only two places after comma")]
public string Level {get; set;}
```